# How forms work in django

Tags: python, django

I am sure this is a silly question but I am trying to understand how forms work in django and I am confused about the action attribute in the template and the httpresponseredirect in views.py

I have the following template:

```
<form action="/play_outcomes/output/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the following view:

```
def getinput(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = get_data(request.POST)

         if form.is_valid():
             down = form.cleaned_data['get_down']
             ytg = form.cleaned_data['get_ytg']
             yfog = form.cleaned_data['get_yfog']
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
     else:
         form = get_data()


     return render(request, 'play_outcomes/getinput.html', {'form': form})
```

And finally in forms.py

```
class get_data(forms.Form):
    get_down = forms.IntegerField(label = "Enter a down")
    get_ytg = forms.IntegerField(label = "Enter yards to go")
    get_yfog = forms.IntegerField(label = "Enter yards from own goal")
```

When I go to `play_outcomes/getinput` my form comes up. When I press 'submit' it directs shows the `play_outcomes/output` page, presumably because that is what is specified by the `<form action` variable.

Anyway, my question is what is the purpose of the return `HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')` after it has checked `form.is_valid()`. This is `TRUE` so it must execute this code. But this return seems redundant.

Please can someone enlighten me on what the `return` in the `views.py` is doing

Comment: There is no point; nothing in the POST block will ever get executed. But you wouldn't write code like this. The form action should point at getinput as well.

Comment: @Daniel -- I assume you mean in the getinput(request) function? So what does get executed?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the form action with `action=""`. Everything should continue working normally, since your view handles *both* GET requests (to show an empty form) and POST requests (to process when a form is submitted). When you press "Submit", your browser is sending the form data back to the exact same place it got the original web page from. Same URL, same view (`getinput()`), same template file (`play_outcomes/getinput.html`).

Normally, right before that `HttpResponseRedirect()` part, you'd include some logic to save the content of that form, email a user, do some calculation, etc. At that point, since the user is all done with that page, you typically redirect them to somewhere else on your site.

Edit: empty action

Comment: Got it - that's very helpful. Thanks